# How do I setup OWASP Zap as an MITM proxy to debug HTTP web service calls?

Tags: macos, proxy, owasp, zap

I want to capture HTTP requests and responses on OS X. The requests are being sent from a Ruby-on-Rails server to an Elasticsearch server, thus I cannot use the builtin logging provided by Chrome or another browser.

In my elasticsearch.yaml, I have changed Elasticsearch to use port 9400. Using a web browser, I verified that it now honors requests to that port and not 9200.

In ZAP, I have set Options > Local Proxy > Port to 9200.

I expect my Rails app to continue to send messages to port 9200, have them intercepted by ZAP and forwarded to Elasticsearch on port 9400, have Elasticsearch send a response back to ZAP and have ZAP forward that along to the Rails app.

I do not see what I expect happening. Attempts using a web browser (in place of the rails app) to request from port 9200 return "Bad Format".

What additional configuration do I need to do to ZAP, and how do I tell it to start? How do I tell it to forward requests to port 9400?

UPDATE: I think what I am asking for is called a "reverse proxy".

UPDATE: On the google group for OWASP, I learned that ZAP is not used as a reverse proxy. I ended up going with mitmproxy, which was easy to install and use and has fewer features, hence is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Under the heading I would not (only) understand how to redirect a port with a proxy (specific), but how ZAP can be set up as a MITM proxy (general). Therefore a general addition for the ethical hackers out there:

ZAP is a proxy. For example, as soon as ZAP is set up as the proxy in the browser settings, it can read (if not encyrpted) the communication between a webserver and the browser. I tested firefox and ZAP V 2.9.0.

To manipulate the HTTP-traffic with OWASP ZAP, I found the following possibility: First in the tools menu tab it is needed to set the "Toogle Break on All Requests" and "Toogle Break on All Responses" (the green traffic light in the toolbar will turn red). Afterwards every single request and response comes before it is sent in a tab of the workspace window called "Break". Here it is easy to manipulate them before sending them with the "Submit and Step to Next Request or Response" menu item. With "Submit and Continue to next Breakpoint" it is possible to turnoff the break until the next breakpoint. Also ports could be manipulated here.

But to your specific case: If the communication would be between the browser (with OWASP ZAP set as proxy under port 9200) and a webserver, the requested port in the browser needs to be port 9400. Tested for firefox would the browser handle it in the background, to send the traffic first to ZAP with port 9200. But as it seems from your question, your Ruby-on-Rails server requires that the proxy dynamically redirects the ports.